# When does Hesse curve coincide with the original curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

We know that the inflection points of the plane complex curve are exactly the non-singular points where the Hessian determinant is zero. But sometimes Hesse curve coincides with the original curve. The possible example is the curve $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=0$, which is the product of three lines.

Is it true that a curve can be a subset of a Hasse curve only in similar degenerate cases?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a curve (that may or may not coincide with its Hesse curve just to have an idea about these curves).

Comment: @user25406 I've corrected the question. The curve $x^3+y^3+z^3-3\lambda xyz=0$ is singular iff $\lambda^3=1$. In this case it coincedes with the Hasse curve. Otherwise we have an elliptic curve with usual 9 inflection points.